# UIButton titleLabel NOT changing

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two View Controllers : "A" (main View Controller) & "B" (second View Controller). In VC "A", there is a button who's title I would like to set in VC "B" via a Table View. When the user selects a row from the Table View, the button's title should be set to the selected row. After much editing and testing I think I have isolated the problem to when I set the button's label in VC "A", following the selection of the Table View. Here is the code from where I think the problem is (View Controller "A"):

```
//firstParameterString = the button label's string which I set in VC "B"

- (void)setButtonLabels {
    NSLog(@"%@", firstParameterString); 

    if (self.firstParameterString == nil) {
        [self.firstParameter setTitle:@"M" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    else {
        [self.firstParameter setTitle:firstParameterString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@", [self.firstParameter titleForState:UIControlStateNormal]);
}
```

When I run the code in Simulator, the first NSLog returns the correct value, however the second NSLog returns a value of "(null)". I don't understand why this isn't working...I had it up and running in another project I was working on. Any help or comments would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's because the titleLabel isn't what you are setting, so it is null (hasn't been created yet).
Also, you are setting the title of firstParameter, but trying to check secondParameter.

You want to instead check:

```
[self.firstParameter titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Thanks...careless mistake. However, in the logger, the title still shows up as "(null)". I dont understand because the first NSLog returns the correct value (NSString).

Comment: Try `NSLog(@"%@",self.firstParameter);` Most Likely, this will log `null` as well. This is because the error is most likely because you have never created `self.firstParameter` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Would your try

```
[self.firstParameter setTitle:self.firstParameterString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.firstParameter setTitle:self.firstParameterString forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[self.firstParameter setTitle:self.firstParameterString forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
[self.firstParameter setTitle:self.firstParameterString forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```